# Trying to connect old speaker to old sound system

Tags: audio, setup, adapters

I hope I am asking in the right place. I don't know much about audio technology, so please excuse my terminology.

I have an old sound system whose speaker stopped working, and I have a set of two old speakers that can't be connected directly. I'd like to know if there is a way to connect them anyway, via some sort of adapter. I'm adding images:

1. This  is the outlet in the sound system
   [image: System Outlet]
2. This is the speaker cable
   [image: This is the speaker cable]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what the connectors are i can not tell you if an adapter is available for them but there is several combinations of things you can do.

1. **Cut the connectors off you old speakers**; If you are never going to repair ( *even if you do you can still reattach them later* ) then you just cut them off and wire them onto your replacement speakers. Positive to positive and negative to negative. You can solder or use crimp connectors or just twist them together Tape them real good individually.
2. **Search** on EBay  or stereo forum classifieds for parts for you stereo model and purchase the ends for the speakers or buy some more speakers of the same kind you had.
3. **Take it into an electronic repair shop** and have them replace the connector sockets on the stereo head unit with a more universal kind, i prefer [5way binding posts](https://www.parts-express.com/mini-gold-plated-insulated-5-way-binding-post-banana-jack-set-2-red-2-black--320-3375). Then you can use [banana plugs](https://www.parts-express.com/parts-express-banana-plug-pair-compression-type--091-330) or just bind the bare wire into the 5way posts. ( *or learn to solder and do it yourself* )

Do some searching on YouTube concerning speaker connection to educate yourself on the ins and outs of positive and negative in relation to speakers.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Tetsujin we know what they are called now. They are two pin DIN connectors. [Din Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector#Loudspeaker_connector).

I [**found a pair**](https://www.cricklewoodelectronics.com/Pair-of-Red-and-Black-2-pin-DIN-Speaker-Plugs-with-Screw-Terminals.html) that allow you to attach your wires by using a screw clamp connection.

Comment: They're 'speaker DIN' ancient but still available - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hi-Fi-Speaker-Cable-Audio-Connector/dp/B0196P1GO8

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for that.